# How can I update a website running in a private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an AWS website that is running inside a private subnet and I am not sure what the best way is to update it.

I would like something that is non-burdensome, ideally it would be nice to have some EC2 Box (with security groups only allowing select IP's to connect too) running the development page, and then I could simply copy it over to the private EC2 Box with a click of a button.

I am not too familiar with best practices, but the idea of connecting through several EC2 boxes seems burdensome.

Thank You!

Comment: Take a look at https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/01/aws-codedeploy-introduces-blue-green-deployments/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to make use of AWS CodeDeploy. There are other tools as well, but since you are already on/using AWS this might be a good one to start with:

> AWS CodeDeploy is a service that automates code deployments to any
>   instance, including Amazon EC2 instances and instances running
>   on-premises. AWS CodeDeploy makes it easier for you to rapidly release
>   new features, helps you avoid downtime during application deployment,
>   and handles the complexity of updating your applications. You can use
>   AWS CodeDeploy to automate software deployments, eliminating the need
>   for error-prone manual operations, and the service scales with your
>   infrastructure so you can easily deploy to one instance or thousands.

https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I wanted!